# Stop executing JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
$('body').data('data1', '<script type="text/javascript">console.debug('execute');</script><div>example</div>');
```

and:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

when I do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#content').html($('body').data('data1'));
});
```

then JavaScript is executed. How to prevent executing? Is it possible?

Comment: Actually, you get a syntax error. And even if you fix that, what did you expect to happen? If you don't want a script to run, then why are you inserting it into the DOM?

Comment: Sorry for this syntax error. I was writing from memory. This example is the sample of a large problem. Just I must also store JS codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to strip the `script` tags from your HTML string.

```
var p = new DOMParser(),
    doc = p.parseFromString("<html><body>...</body></html>", "text/xml");
$('script', doc).remove();
```

This works with Firefox/Chrome, although I don't know about other browsers. Note this will only work with well-formed (x)html.

EDIT: If you also want the JS, you can amend the previous code thus:

```
var scripts = [];
$('script', doc).remove().each(function() {
  scripts.push($(this).html());
});
```

Mind you, you don't even have to remove the `script` tags. Now that the response is in its separate DOM document, it will not mess up your own scripts, and you can access whatever content you need from it using easy `$('selector', doc)` jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you are going to stop the script from executing is to remove it from your data.  The prototype framework does this using a regular expression like below:

```
  <script[^>]*>([\\S\\s]*?)<\/script>
```

Comment: Hmm, don't parse HTML with Regex? Please?

Comment: I know it is nasty.  However it works quite well.  It is copied straight from the prototype source code.  Doing it this way means that will work with malformed XHTML and will also work in all browsers.

Comment: Good idea. I have removed these tags, but an another way.